# Syncing local XML with web server XML in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have developed an application that has a a XML file in res/xml folder

The details that were there in the xml file were supposed to be static, but we have a new requirement now where the xml file is required to be updated through a Web Server

What are the possible way outs

1. What is the best possible way to read an XML file from a Web server in Android? Sample code will be helpful
2. Once I have read the XML from Web Server, can I modify the XML on the phone?
3. Are there any other possibilities?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the URLConnection to download:

```
public void DownloadFromUrl(String imageURL, String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
        try {
                URL url = new URL("http://yoursite.com/&quot; + imageURL); //you can write here any link
                File file = new File(fileName);

                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.d("ImageManager", "download begining");
                Log.d("ImageManager", "download url:" + url);
                Log.d("ImageManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);
                /* Open a connection to that URL. */
                URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                /*
                 * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                 */
                InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                /*
                 * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                 */
                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                int current = 0;
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                        baf.append((byte) current);
                }

                /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                fos.close();
                Log.d("ImageManager", "download ready in"
                                + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                                + " sec");

        } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
        }

}
```

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device

IBM has some help on this, basically the file will be saved to the an InputStream, which you can work with it from there or save it to a file.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/